# spring security authorization at spring security version 6.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-starter

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    return http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/home/normal")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/products/**")
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().and().build();


}
```

how to write .csrf() ,.authorizeHttpRequests(),.formLogin() because it showing error that is deprecated and marked for removal.I m using springboot 3.2 version and spring security 6.2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)

            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/home/normal").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/products/**").authenticated())

            .formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll())

            .build();
}
```